# Webp image shows up locally but not remotely after deploy

Tags: html, webp

I have this html code which I can see the webp image when I open my html file locally.

[image]

```
<picture>
      <source srcset="images/steve.webp" type="image/webp">
      <source srcset="images/steve.png" type="image/png">
      <img src="images/steve.png" alt="Steve" width="200" height="180">
</picture>
```

But after I deploy it to my website, The image is not showing up.
[image]

When I access to the image directly, I got an error. http://resume.findingsteve.net/images/steve.webp

[image]

But the images are there:

[image]

http://resume.findingsteve.net/images/steve.png is okay. I can see its image.

With relative path, still the same issue

[image]

Comment: Use relative path for the accessing image url

Comment: still the same issue even i use relative path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add MIME types for png file extension in your servers web config

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png" />
   
    </staticContent>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: you mean add webp file extension? since this is share web hosting, i guess i have to contact hosting provider

Comment: Yes, it needs to be updated on the server web config level.